# Поиск слова в Memo

Tags: delphi

В интернетах нагуглил скрипт, который ищет в Memo2 слово, введенное в Edit1, но есть проблема, если, например, у меня в мемо написано ТЕКСТ1 ТЕКСТ2, так вот скрипт упрется в первое слово и дальше не хочет искать, подскажите, как сделать, чтоб при повторном нажатии продолжало искать дальше, то есть чтоб было как в нормальных текстовиках: жмем F3 и нам показывает следующий вариант:

```
var
  Find: string;
  I: integer;
  begin
  Find:=AnsiLowerCase(Edit1.Text);
  for
  i:=0 to
  Memo2.Lines.count-1 do
  if
  pos(AnsiLowerCase (Find),AnsiLowerCase(Memo2.Lines.Text))<>0 then
  begin
  Memo2.setfocus();
  Memo2.SelStart:=pos(AnsiLowerCase(find),AnsiLowerCase(memo2.Lines.Text))-1;
  Memo2.SelLength:=Length(find);
  end;
```

Comment: Ох уж мне эти teh codez from teh internetz! Прямо под самым носом есть манускрипт `delphi.hlp` в котором это подробно расписано.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо функции `Pos` имеет смысл использовать `PosEx`:

```
function PosEx(const SubStr, S: string; Offset: Cardinal = 1): Integer;
```

Параметр `Offset` задает позицию, с которой `PosEx` будет искать совпадение с `SubStr`.

Answer (score 0):

Весь код я писать не буду, лишь подскажу, как можно это сделать.
Вам поможет функция

```
copy(str:string, begin:integer, length:integer);
```

Она может использоваться для обрезания текста. Когда в TMemo найден фрагмент текста, то обрезайте текст в TMemo, начиная с позиции найденного слова+его длина. Все это делайте виртуально, то есть не затрагивайте настоящий текст, работайте с ним через другую переменную лишь получая нужные вам позиции.

Comment: Какой смысл если есть `PosEx`?